# Commenting systems: loading different comment threads through callbacks

Tags: wordpress, comments, disqus

I'm looking for a commenting system with a specific feature, and I wondered if anyone could advise.

I want to be able to load different comment threads without reloading the entire page, via JavaScript callbacks. That means I need a commenting system that allows multiple comment threads to be associated with the same URL, with threads defined by custom IDs.

I've just found out this isn't possible with Disqus. Although Disqus does allow you to associate a [unique ID of your choice with a thread](http://help.disqus.com/entries/103890-how-disqus-uniquely-identifies-and-associates-comment-threads-and-how-to-use-a-custom-identifier), it also requires a unique URL for each comment thread.

Does anyone know a system that does offer the ability to associate multiple comment threads with the same URL, via unique IDs?

Not sure if it's possible with either IntenseDebate or Wordpress - or maybe I need to write a custom Wordpress plugin (the page itself will actually be within a Wordpress install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have no problems creating you own custom comment page by 'hacking' comments.php.
By using jQuery and [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can call a php page where you have code to retrieve custom comments.

But messing about comments.php is not that easy. Therefore [this page](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/unraveling-the-secrets-of-wordpress-commentsphp-file/) might help you get an insight in comments.php

This answer doesn't solve you problem, but hopefully it'll give you some ideas.